# How to upload image with VueJS to Go server

Tags: vue.js, go

I am trying to upload an image from VueJS to a Go server and I am unable to get it working properly.

```
let form = new FormData();
if (this.styling.file !== undefined) {
    form.append('logo', this.styling.file);
}
form.append('something1', this.something.one);
form.append('something2', this.something.two);

this.$http.post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/store', form).then(() => {
    // ...
})
```

Then in Go I can successfully save any details I pass along in the form data. The only thing that is not working is the image I uploaded.

When I do this:

```
form := request.MultipartForm
defer form.RemoveAll()

file, _, err := request.FormFile("logo")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

img, _, err := image.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

It shows me an error: image: unknown format

I tried multiple tutorials on the net, but none give me a way to store the uploaded image through Go on my server so far :(

I also tried the following methods, which results in an error "open test.jpg : the system cannot find the file".

```
form := request.MultipartForm
defer form.RemoveAll()

in, header, err := request.FormFile("logo")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
defer in.Close()

out, err := os.OpenFile(header.Filename, os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
defer out.Close()
io.Copy(out, in)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and headeach I found the solution which was quite simple in my case.

```
out, err := os.OpenFile(header.Filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
```

Just had to add a append and create.